# Is there a way to display characters in a for loop without duplicating code?

Tags: swift

I'm still very new to learning Swift and have a frame that displays the alphabet in it evenly.

I have 3 for loops in which letters A-X are displayed in 4 rows with 6 columns while Y and Z are in the 5th row in columns 2-3 (so it is centered). However, to achieve this, I had to duplicate my code. Is there a better way to go about this so I do not have to duplicate the code?

```
let allLetters = (65...90).map { Character(Unicode.Scalar($0)) }
    let width = 80
    let height = 80

    for row in 0..<4 {
        for col in 0..<6 {
            let letterButton = UIButton(type: .system)
                letterButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
                letterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(letterTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            let frame = CGRect(x: col * width, y: row * height, width: width, height: height)
            letterButton.frame = frame
            
            buttonsView.addSubview(letterButton)
            letterButtons.append(letterButton)
        }
    }
   
        for col in 2..<4 {
            let letterButton = UIButton(type: .system)
                letterButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
                letterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(letterTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
           
            let frame = CGRect(x: col * width, y: 4 * height, width: width, height: height)
            letterButton.frame = frame
        
            buttonsView.addSubview(letterButton)
            letterButtons.append(letterButton)
    }
            
    for (index, button) in letterButtons.enumerated() {
        button.setTitle(String(allLetters[index]), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify and improve the performance, removing two for loops like this:

```
let allLetters = (65...90).map { Character(Unicode.Scalar($0)) }
let width = 80
let height = 80

var letterIndex = 0
let lastRowIndex = 4
let defaultRowColumnRange = 0..<6
let lastRowColumnRange = 2..<4

for row in 0...lastRowIndex {
    let rangeForRow = row == lastRowIndex ? lastRowColumnRange : defaultRowColumnRange
    for col in rangeForRow {
        let letterButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        letterButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
        letterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(letterTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        if allLetters.count > letterIndex {
            letterButton.setTitle(String(allLetters[letterIndex]), for: .normal)
            letterIndex += 1
        }
        
        let frame = CGRect(x: col * width, y: row * height, width: width, height: height)
        letterButton.frame = frame
        
        view.addSubview(letterButton)
        letterButtons.append(letterButton) // Might not be necessary anymore
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would still move all the button manipulations into its own function:

```
func addButton(letter: Character, x: Int, y: Int) {

    let letterButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    letterButton.setTitle(String(letter), for: .normal)
    letterButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
    letterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(letterTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    let frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    letterButton.frame = frame
        
    buttonsView.addSubview(letterButton)
    letterButtons.append(letterButton)
}
```

Because this provides a nice isolation to all ui operations. Even if you replace your repetitive code with this function, you've got the improvement.

But also assume

```
let numberOfLettersPerRow = 6
```

You know how many buttons will be in each row:

```
let buttonsInCurrentRow = min(numberOfLettersPerRow, allLetters.count - row * numberOfLettersPerRow) // i.e. 6 or less
```

So you can then decide if buttons will be back to back, or there's some empty space before and after them:

```
let gap = (numberOfLettersPerRow - buttonsInCurrentRow) * width / 2
```

This gap will be 0 for rows where `numberOfLettersPerRow == buttonsInCurrentRow`, but will be more than 0 for rows that have  `numberOfLettersPerRow < buttonsInCurrentRow`, and we want it to be half of total gap (so there's equal space in front and back)

So now you place your button like this:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: gap + col * width, y: row * height, width: width, height: height)
```

And then you run your loop over buttons you have, rather than over rows and columns. Why? because if you change your mind tomorrow about how to place your buttons, you don't need to change much of the code:

```
for i in 0...allLetters.count - 1 {

    let row = Int(i / numberOfLettersPerRow)
    let col = i % numberOfLettersPerRow
    let buttonsInCurrentRow = min(numberOfLettersPerRow, allLetters.count - row * numberOfLettersPerRow)
    let gap = (numberOfLettersPerRow - buttonsInCurrentRow) * width / 2
    addButton(letter: allLetters[i], x: gap + col * width, y: row * height)
}
```

And that's it.